# Heap Confusion and Heap Array

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, heap

I have the following heap...

```
                                   80
                                /      \
                               76        74
                              /  \      /    \
                             37  32     39   66
                            / \  / \    / \
                           20 26 18 28 29  6
```

My classmate and I received different answers when trying to remove 80 from the heap. The array I received after replacing `80` with `6` was `76,37,74,26,32,39,66,20,6,18,28,29`. Is that correct?

Tree after work was done

```
                                    76                                                              
                                /      \
                               37        74
                              /  \      /    \
                             26  32     39   66
                            / \  / \    / 
                           20 6 18 28 29
```

Comment: What is your logic to come to this particular answer?

Comment: @BalwinderSingh replaced `80` with `6`, then since `76` > `74` I switched `6` with `76`, then since `37` was greater than `32` I switched `6` with `37` and then since `26` was greater than `20` I switched `6` with `26`.

Comment: In your original heap, there are 13 entries. After replacing 80, in your solution, there are 9 entries. What happened to rest of them?

Comment: @BalwinderSingh just realized that, doing my work I got lazy and was only drawing the half of the tree I was working on, I have now fixed my mistake in my question.

Comment: Does that mean your problem wasn't really a problem? Just a transcription error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your heap is correct.  What did your classmate come up with?

Comment: I looked it over and he replaced 80 with 66 instead of 6. Thanks!